# Node JS request from API

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, electron

I would like to make an application for my organization so we can see our customers, invoices and quotes very easily. I have managed to get a response from the RESTful API form Moneybird (which is the program we will be using) looking like the following (for privacy reasons I blanked out personal details):

```
{
    "id": "206357083043398674",
    "administration_id": "BLANK",
    "company_name": "BLANK",
    "firstname": "BLANK",
    "lastname": "BLANK",
    "address1": "BLANK",
    "address2": "",
    "zipcode": "BLANK",
    "city": "BLANK",
    "country": "NL",
    "phone": "BLANK",
    "delivery_method": "Email",
    "customer_id": "9",
    "tax_number": "BLANK",
    "chamber_of_commerce": "BLANK",
    "bank_account": "BLANK",
    "attention": "BLANK",
    "email": "BLANK",
    "email_ubl": true,
    "send_invoices_to_attention": "BLANK",
    "send_invoices_to_email": "BLANK",
    "send_estimates_to_attention": "BLANK",
    "send_estimates_to_email": "BLANK",
    "sepa_active": false,
    "sepa_iban": "BLANK",
    "sepa_iban_account_name": "BLANK",
    "sepa_bic": "BLANK",
    "sepa_mandate_id": "",
    "sepa_mandate_date": null,
    "sepa_sequence_type": "FRST",
    "credit_card_number": "",
    "credit_card_reference": "",
    "credit_card_type": null,
    "tax_number_validated_at": "2017-1118T15:04:32.107Z",
    "tax_number_valid": true,
    "invoice_workflow_id": "BLANK",
    "estimate_workflow_id": "BLANK",
    "created_at": "20171118T15:04:31.825Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-1118T15:39:03.345Z",
    "version": 1511019543,
    "sales_invoices_url": "BLANK",
    "notes": [],
    "custom_fields": [],
    "events": [{
            "administration_id": "BLANK",
            "user_id": "BLANK",
            "action": "contact_changed",
            "link_entity_id": null,
            "link_entity_type": null,
            "data": {
                "changes": {
                    "send_invoices_to_email": ["BLANK", "BLANK"]
                }
            },
            "created_at": "2017-11-18T15:39:03.373Z",
            "updated_at": "2017-11-18T15:39:03.373Z"
        },
        {
            "administration_id": "BLANK",
            "user_id": "BLANK",
            "action": "contact_changed",
            "link_entity_id": null,
            "link_entity_type": null,
            "data": {
                "changes": {
                    "send_invoices_to_email": ["BLANK", "BLANK"]
                }
            },
            "created_at": "2017-11-18T15:25:43.938Z",
            "updated_at": "2017-11-18T15:25:43.938Z"
        },
        {
            "administration_id": "BLANK",
            "user_id": "BLANK",
            "action": "contact_created",
            "link_entity_id": null,
            "link_entity_type": null,
            "data": null,
            "created_at": "2017-11-18T15:04:31.860Z",
            "updated_at": "2017-11-18T15:04:31.860Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

I managed to get this response using the following code:

```
request({
        url: 'https://moneybird.com/api/v2/'+accountID+'/contacts/206357083043398674.json?',
        auth: {
            'bearer': accessToken
        },
        method: 'POST'
    }, function(error, response, data) {
        body.data = data;
        mainWindow.webContents.send('user:view', body.data);
    });
```

Obviously there is no more console.log(); because I would like to display every user on his/her own line in a unordered list.

I don't know how I can use the information I get from my request to the index.html file and make it readable.

I am writing a desktop app using Electron and Node.JS.

Answer (score 0):

I found the awnser at the following link:

http://stackabuse.com/the-node-js-request-module/

> Using the options object, this request uses the GET method to retrieve
>   JSON data directly from Reddit, which is returned as a string in the
>   body field. From here, you can use JSON.parse and use the data as a
>   normal JavaScript object.

Now I can just do options.id and have the customer's ID.